# Блокирование обозревателя объектов при изменении таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Подскажите, а это нормально, что если запустить продолжительный ALTER TABLE на какой-нибудь большой таблице, то обозреватель объектов в SSMS не дает обновить список таблиц в БД, нельзя посмотреть хранимки в БД и все такое...

Т.е на глухо блочится возможность чего-нибудь посмотреть в БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это особенность работы SSMS с системными представлениями БД.

`ALTER TABLE` устанавливает *Sch-M*-блокировку на таблице с целью монополизировать право на структурные изменения объекта. И, заодно, защищает объект вообще от любых посягательств извне, т.к. *Sch-M*-блокировка ни с какими другими не совместима. Это, однако, не является препятствием для получения информации о *других* таблицах.

Если, например, создать пару таблиц

```
CREATE TABLE A (N int);
CREATE TABLE B (N int);
```

Изменить одну из них

```
BEGIN TRAN;
GO
ALTER TABLE A
    ALTER COLUMN N bigint NOT NULL;
GO
```

и затем, не фиксируя и не откатывая изменения (и не закрывая сессию), выполнить в *отдельной* сессии запрос

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = N'B';
```

то можно получить информацию о неизменённой таблице. Также можно посмотреть информацию об остальных неизменённых таблицах

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables WITH (READPAST);
```

Однако посмотреть информацию об изменённой таблице или обо всех таблицах

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = N'A';
SELECT * FROM sys.tables;
```

не получится.

Обозреватель объектов в SSMS не может обновить список таблиц, потому что SSMS, так же обращаясь к *sys.tables*, запрашивает метаданные *всех* таблиц. Представление *sys.tables* ссылается на *sys.objects$*, а *sys.objects$* обращается к системной таблице *sys.sysschobjs*, в которой лежат заголовки объектов

```
id          name nsid nsclass status type pid pclass intprop created                 modified                status2
----------- ---- ---- ------- ------ ---- --- ------ ------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------
...
1205579333  A    1    0       917504 U    0   1      1       2019-09-13 00:00:00.000 2019-09-13 00:00:00.000 0
...
```

Запрос, который делает SSMS вызывает сканирование *sys.sysschobjs*, но `ALTER TABLE` меняет строку в *sys.sysschobjs*, соответствующую заголовку объекта (как минимум обновляет дату изменения) и устанавливает на неё *X*-блокировку, поэтому SSMS приходится ждать или прерываться по тайм-ауту.

Answer (score 4):

Полагаю, да, т.к.:

`ALTER TABLE` накладывает блокировку изменения схемы (`SCH-M`) для таблицы, чтобы убедиться, что никакие другие соединения не ссылаются даже на метаданные таблицы во время изменения, за исключением операций с индексами (`ONLINE`), которые требуют очень короткой блокировки `SCH-M` в конце операции.